# Rails render related models within scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to load related objects within a scope when rendering a json response from my server / api.

```
render :json => @feed.to_json({
  :include => {
    :feed_tracks => {
      :methods => :current_feed_tracks,
      :include => :track
    }
  }
})
```

Basically, I want to only return `feed_tracks` that are marked as `current`. I have a scope on the feed_tracks model called `current`:

```
  scope :current, -> { where(current: true) }
```

`Feed` has many feed tracks, each feed track has a track associated with it.

I want to return only feed tracks marked as current and pull in their associated track.

The above hash I have returns all feed tracks, even those marked as not current.

I am looking for a response that looks like this:

```
feed: {
  id: 123,
  feed_tracks: [
    {
      id: 123,
      current: true
    },
    {
      id: 456,
      current: true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was to include it like it was an attribute of the feed

```
render :json => @feed.to_json({
  :include => {
    :current_feed_tracks => {
      :include => :track
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
feed_tracks.current
```

Answer (score 0):

Try @feed.feed_tracks.current.includes(:track).map(&:track)

Comment: this does not address my question